# Why does the list in the Adapter used before filling it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android Studio so I'm trying to make a RecyclerView with its Adapter and ViewHolder, the Adapter class needs a list to make each item in the list, the list should be filled from database from FireBase.
the FireBase reference retrieve the data needed and add them to the list, but the list always stays empty, Why?

Here's the code :

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView rView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rView = findViewById(R.id.rView);
        layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rView.setLayoutManager(layout);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ProjectAdapter reAdapter = new ProjectAdapter();
        rView.setAdapter(reAdapter);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectAdapter.ProjectViewHolder> {

    private List<Project> proList;
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageRef;
    private Project p;

    public ProjectAdapter(){
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        proList = new ArrayList<>();
        firestore.collection("Projects").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if(e == null){
                for(DocumentSnapshot doc : documentSnapshots){
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "onComplete: " + doc.getString("proName"));
                    p = new Project();
                    p.setProName(doc.getString("proName"));
                    p.setProDes(doc.getString("proDescription"));
                    p.setProPic(doc.getString("picture"));
                    System.out.println(p.getProName());
                    proList.add(p);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public static class ProjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView proName;
    public ImageView proPic;
    public TextView proBreif;

    public ProjectViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        proName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.proName);
        proBreif = itemView.findViewById(R.id.DesctextView);
        proPic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.proPic);
    }
}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProjectViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_item, viewGroup, false);
        return  new ProjectViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjectViewHolder projectViewHolder, int i) {
        projectViewHolder.proName.setText(proList.get(i).getProName());
        projectViewHolder.proBreif.setText(proList.get(i).getProDes());
    [projectViewHolder.proPic.setImageURI(Uri.parse(proList.get(i).getProPic()));][1]
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        System.out.println(proList.size()); // the output always 0, it got called before retrieving form the database.
        return proList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
        return R.layout.activity_item;
    }
}
```

the output is :

the names are the data retrieved from database.

Comment: please attach your database photo

Comment: well, the retrieved data from the database are OK nothing wrong with them, but it starts to make the adapter first, then retrieve the data to put it in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using one of Firestore's built in adapters instead - the Firestore Recycler Adapter.   https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore

It is built especially for this purpose and makes it much easier to implement.